# What is the best type to use for returning an image in my C# library project?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I'm making a project that will scrap information about a movie and return all sorts of goodies. This will be a .dll that other developers will use in their projects.

For example, if they want to set a pictureBox image to the movies poster, what would be the best way to handle my library returning the image?

```
//Set the image to The Matrix poster.
pictureBox1.Image = MyLibrary.GetPoster("The Matrix");
```

Should I return an Image? A Byte[] array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say return a [System.Drawing.Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Return an image.

Answer (score 0):

I think returning System.Drawing.Bitmap makes it easy to use